# Data tables from Sorokin's Social and Cultural Dynamics

Tags: data-request, historical, books, social-process

The title says it all, does there exist in digital form, like csv-files or spreadsheets, the (very many) data tables from Pitirim A Sorokin's Social and Cultural Dynamics, all four volumes:

```
I   Fluctuations of Forms of Art
II  Fluctuations of Systems of Truth, Ethics, and Law
III Fluctuations of Social Relationships, War, and Revolution
IV  Basic Problems, Principles, and Methods
```

Comment: @JanDoggen this is a valid answer. I suggest you convert it to one

Answer (score 2):

If you mean all the tables that are displayed throughout the text, one option would be to register at Scribd (one month free), download the files from there:

[Volume 1](https://www.scribd.com/document/98206669/Sorokin-Dynamics-Vol-I-Fluctuation-of-Forms-of-Art-Ch-1-2-Missing-Searchable#) (Chapters 1 and 2 missing)
[Volume 2](https://www.scribd.com/document/106771841/Sorokin-Dynamics-Vol-II-Fluctuation-of-Systems-of-Truth-Ethics-Law)
[Volume 3](https://www.scribd.com/document/106771873/Sorokin-Dynamics-Vol-III-Fluctuation-of-Social-Relationships-War-Revolution-Ch-1-2-Missing) (Chapters 1 and 2 missing)
[Volume 4](https://www.scribd.com/document/106771922/Sorokin-Dynamics-Vol-IV-Basic-Problems-Principles-And-Methods)

Then cut and paste the tables and pull them through an OCR program. That's not in CSV and still a lot of work, though
(especially since the file appears to be OCRed from another source, resulting in weird formatting artefacts like *page 12<sup>3</sup>*).

If you have access to the written volumes, you would have to type over the tables from the 2+2 missing chapters.

After all that, do the world a favor, place the results somewhere online, and write that as an answer here ;-)

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, links to volumes 2-4 weren't included in the answer during bounty award period. Refresher bounty value is 100 :-(.